# Creating Macro button with multiple functions?

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I am trying to sort my excel sheet by first and last name and I was wondering if it was possible for me to assign multiple macros to one button? Let's say I click once, it sorts by first name; click again and it sorts by last name. Is this possible? I asked as I couldn't find similar questions.

Here's my code

**First Name**

```
        Columns ("D:D").Select 
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1") .Sort.SortFields.clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1") .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D1"), 
    Sorton::x=SortOnValues, Order:=xlDesending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    with ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1") .Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:K505")
    Header = X1No
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = x1TopToBottom 
    .SortMethod = x1PinYin 
    .Apply

    End With
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-495

    End Sub
```

Obviously the other code is similar but with descending instead of ascending.

Comment: This may not even require a macro or button at all depending on your needs.  If you format your data as an Excel Table (Home --> Format as Table), you can sort columns directly using the filter buttons.  

If you are building out an application that requires independent controls (macro buttons, etc) then you may still want to use table structure so you can dynamically add/delete rows and columns as needed. I personally prefer to work with ListObjects (how tables are represented in VBA) versus ranges, particularly so you can acces columns by name, more easily manipulate data and structure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set a global variable for the state and toggle it to have the macro bound to the button do different stuff. (this is assuming you want the function of the button to toggle after every click)

```
' global state variable
Dim State As Boolean

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ' initialize state
    State = True
End Sub

Sub mymacro()
    If State Then
        ' do stuff 1
    Else
        ' do stuff 2
    End If

    ' toggle state
    State = Not State
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One button can only run one macro. However, you might let the macro do different things depending upon the current selection. For example, if the user selects a cell in the `Name` column the sort is done on the name, in ascending order, and if the selection is in another column it is done on the first name, in descending order.

The code below sets both the sort key and the sort order relative to the selection. Therefore you don't need two different macros.

```
Sub SortByColumn()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Clm As Long
    Dim SortOrder As XlSortOrder

    With Selection
        Set Ws = .Worksheet
        Clm = .Column
        If Clm = 4 Then             ' column #4 = column D
            SortOrder = xlDescending
        Else
            ' sort on column 1 by default
            Clm = 1                 ' column #1 = column A
            SortOrder = xlAscending
        End If
    End With

    With Ws.Sort
        With .SortFields
            .Clear
            .Add Key:=Ws.Cells(1, Clm), _
                 Sorton:=xlSortOnValues, _
                 Order:=SortOrder, _
                 DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With

        .SetRange Ws.Range("A1:K505")
        .Header = X1No
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = x1TopToBottom
        .SortMethod = x1PinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-495
End Sub
```

Note that the sorting action doesn't require anything to be selected.